# Presto view is faster than table

Tags: presto

I am having a table which is in raw format contains nested json.Also we have a view on top of that raw table which is in pure tabular format or extracted values from json tags.

SO if we query raw table and view which one will run faster.Is there any way we can improve the performance.

Answer (score 4):

Presto view is always as fast as querying underlying table. This is because a view is replaced with its defining query during query planning time.